How to change the magento2 layout to all options in the personal area?
is there a faster way to change the layout from 2columns-left to 3columns to all the personal area pages (account, wishlist, orders etc..) ?
i just got done creating this file:

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Vendor/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_index.xml

and adding this code:
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>

    </body>
</page>

and it worked too, only to find out that if i click on the other pages from the dropdown menu, "orders" for example, the layout remains as 2columns-left.
Is there a way to change the layout to multiple pages (not all of them!) that is faster than overriding every single .xml file?

You can try the below code.
<!-- File path: app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_custom.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=" urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <!-- Apply 3columns layout to specific pages -->
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="page_layout" xsi:type="string">3columns</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceContainer>

        <!-- Customer Account Dashboard -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard" ifconfig="customer/startup/redirect_dashboard">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="page_layout" xsi:type="string">3columns</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

        <!-- Customer Wishlist -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer.wishlist" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="page_layout" xsi:type="string">3columns</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

        <!-- Customer Orders -->
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="page_layout" xsi:type="string">3columns</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>


